# How to solve error with appeal to my rest-api hosted on http from my reactjs-app hosted on https

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, https, fetch

I have an error with my fetch function in reactjs: when I request data from the rest-api (ASP.NET) hosted on http, my app, which is hosted on Firebase (https) throws an error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://[my-domain].firebaseapp.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://***.***.***.***:*****/filter1/filter2'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Rest hosted on linux by ASP.NET. We already tried make a SSL certificate by .NET CORE option.

```js
fetch(`http://host-ip:port/filter1/filter2`, {
                        method      : 'GET',
                        mode        : 'cors',
                        credentials : 'same-origin',
                    }).then(res  => res.json())
                        .then(json => {
                            this.setState(
                                { 
                                    //some operations
                                }
                            )
                    })
```

It can be fixed by installing SSL certificate, but we haven't special domain-name (only ip-address). Can it be solved without any cunning operations with domain and certificates? And can we leave it on our ip without transition to domain?

Answer (score 0):

**Yeah**

You should use your `Rest-Api` over `https`. Install valid `SSL` certificate to your `Rest-Api Server` and configure is correctly.

You can create a `sub-domain` for your `rest-api` using adding `DNS A Record` and Install SSL for that domain.

**I am using**

APP : https://myapp.com (https)

API : (my-rest-api-aws-ip) (http)

**IN DNS (A Record)**

api.myapp.com >>>> (my-rest-api-aws-ip)

Then, I installed free SSL certificate for **api.myapp.com** using [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org)